# How to set ALL the replication to DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, deadlock, transactional-replication

I have just got this email here:
[image]

Then looking at the sql server log I find this deadlock was caused by one of our procedures (that was the victim) against the replication.

[image]

O.K. in this case in particular I noticed that this specific procedure could be tuned, I even found a missing index, as you can see below.

[image]

But this same situation has happened so many times, I would have had the procedure won, the replication was the victim, and I would deal with the procedure later on.

How can I put this:

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
```

everywhere, **in every replication transaction**?

this is to check it out:

```
    SELECT session_id,deadlock_priority 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
    WHERE SESSION_ID = @@SPID
```

[image]

How

Comment: You can set the Snapshot Agent's PublisherDeadlockPriority property to -1, in order to resolve deadlocks that may occur between the Snapshot Agent and user applications during snapshot generation; however, that is only one agent and only the snapshot process.

Comment: You want to address the underlying problem. Dont set the deadlock priority. Have you tried creating the index and test out ? That will help you.

Comment: @Kin the problem is a conflict between constant updates and being able to run reports without facing deadlocks. the replication would catch up later, that is not a problem in this case. Other thing I would consider  is READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation set ON. Still I prefer to set the replication to lose. I am dealing with the indexes too.

Comment: Using READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT worked for me when I had this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a [good setup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196239/22336) and [monitoring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13914/22336) the tempdb
we opted and used the [READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54681/22336) as described in the comments.

How to implement Read Committed Snapshot and how it is different to Snapshot has been nicely described (including links explaining how to set it up) [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206209/22336).

> In addition, READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT (henceforth called RCSI) will
> only give you some properties of optimistic concurrency. RCSI and
> Snapshot (SI) differ in three main ways:
>
> 1. RCSI will be used immediately by all RC isolation queries.
> 2. RCSI provides a point-in-time (snapshot) view of the database for a single statement.
> 3. SI provides a point-in-time view for an entire transaction.
> 4. SI can have write conflicts.

also quoted from the [same source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206209/22336):

> Other useful details relating some gotchas and caveats when using
> RCSI/SI can be found in these articles:
>
> - [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)
> - [Read Committed Snapshot Isolation: Writers Block Writers (RCSI)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-writers-block-rcsi/)